# Reset inspection light on Seat Ibiza ST 2013

Tags: service, warning-light, seat-ibiza, service-intervals

Just bought a Seat Ibiza ST (2013) and noticed that the 'spanner' icon is display on the dash which normally indicates a service interval (seen here: https://seventrumpet.com/how-to-reset-service-oil-light-on-your-new-seat-ibiza/)

I tried the following:

1) Turn ignition off.

2) Hold down 0.0/Set button to left of speedometer.

3) Whilst holding button, turn ignition on but do not start engine.

4) Release button and press button on right of rev counter.

This should clear the service interval warning but my dash says 'INSPEC_' instead rather than 'SERVICE' which appears to be the norm online.

Does anyone know how to reset the INSPECT warning that I am getting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Ignition on. Ignition off. Turn on hazard and leave on.press and hold 0.0./set turn ign on while holding down. Release and hold time set button approx 20sec.release and turn ign off.
Worked for me